# Undefined operator '*' for input arguments of type 'struct'

Tags: matlab

MATLAB :
vso' is graph based visual saliency map (gbvs) of original image, and 'vsd' is graph based visual saliency map (gbvs) of blurred version of the same image.

```
          vso=gbvs('../images/I03.bmp'); 
          vsd=gbvs('../images/i03_17_5.bmp');
```

Trying to find out similarity map between these both image as -

```
          Svs=(2*vso*vsd+cvs)/(vso^2+vsd^2+cvs);
```

where cvs is constant, cvs =1.27

Error is : **Undefined operator '*' for input arguments of type 'struct'**

Comment: You will have to tell us what the `gbvs` function does, in particular what its outputs are.

Comment: Your variables `vso` and `vsd` are not scalar or numeric array, they are of type [`structure`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html). You cannot _multiply_ two structures together, hence Matlab telling you the multiply operator `*` does not exist for this data type.

Comment: How to multiply these vso and vsd ,

Answer (score 0):

vso=gbvs('../images/I03.bmp')

vso =

```
         master_map: [24x32 double]
 master_map_resized: [384x512 double]
top_level_feat_maps: {[24x32 double]  [24x32 double]  [24x32 double]}
          map_types: {'dklcolor'  'intensity'  'orientation'}
      intermed_maps: [1x1 struct]
        rawfeatmaps: [1x1 struct]
         paramsUsed: [1x1 struct]
```

> > vsd=gbvs('../images/i03_17_5.bmp')

vsd =

```
         master_map: [24x32 double]
 master_map_resized: [384x512 double]
top_level_feat_maps: {[24x32 double]  [24x32 double]  [24x32 double]}
          map_types: {'dklcolor'  'intensity'  'orientation'}
      intermed_maps: [1x1 struct]
        rawfeatmaps: [1x1 struct]
         paramsUsed: [1x1 struct]
```

These are variable struct type...